# Unique constraint violation on primary key column with sequence provided id

Tags: oracle, hibernate, unique-constraint

We are using Hibernate to insert rows into an Oracle table, with a sequence providing the ID's for the primary key column. When doing an insert, we get:

> ORA-00001: unique constraint (TABLE_A.PK_ID) violated

How is this possible, if we rely on a sequence for unique ids?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that somehow the sequence became out of sync. The `MY_SEQUENCE.nextVal` must be higher than the highest ID in the table.

That means, `select MY_SEQUENCE.nextVal from DUAL;` must be higher than `select max(ta.ID) from TABLE_A ta;`

You need to update the sequence:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE MY_SEQUENCE INCREMENT BY 10000;
```

*I didn't have the permission to run the above statement, so I just held down the execute button on `select MY_SEQUENCE.nextVal from DUAL;`* for a while. It is still quicker than getting a DBA involved.

Comment: I can't imagine this being a niche problem. Is there any feature that allows me to set up my sequence to just skip existing values?